# Downloading and writing images from an array of urls crashing iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, saving-data, data-retrieval

I am writing images to the directory of my app using the following code in a separate thread

```
for (int j =0; j<[sorted count]; j++) {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[sorted objectAtIndex:j]]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    if (image!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[sorted objectAtIndex:j]);
        [images addObject:image];
    }
}
```

and

```
for (int k=0;k<[images count];k++)
{
    NSString *temp = [[sorted objectAtIndex:k]lastPathComponent];
    NSString *imagePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:temp];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([images objectAtIndex:k], 1.0f);
    [data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

}
```

But a weird thing is last two images are not getting written
I've tried everything but it doesn't seem to work.
Anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: How many images are you downloading and how large are they?  Have you tried downloading and writing one at a time so you don't try to cram them all in memory at once?

Comment: It differs based on the xml. About 168 images with a total size of over 250 mb.

Comment: Well that's it.  or at least a contributing factor.  There is no way you can handle 250mb at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what could be causing your issue, but `UIKit` is not thread safe, so this could be the cause. You could try and execute your code on the main thread just to troubleshoot it (and check that it is correct), then, if my guess is right, look for a workaround.

In looking for a workaround, possibly [performSelector:onMainThread:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a) could help.

Comment: But downloading and saving from the main thread causes my UI to freeze, the first reason why i started a separate thread.

Comment: I was just suggesting a way to troubleshoot your code without having the not-multithreaded UIKit problem... as to a workaround, you could execute on the main thread the conversion (`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, `UIImage imageWithData`) and once you have the `NSData`, write/read to file in a separate thread. If the issue has to do with UIKit multithreading, then I see no other way.